# Update/Edit Data - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, edit, insert-update

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yceGi.png)I have looked through the pages and cannot seem to find an answer.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I have gotten the code to work for updating the data in the sheet from from VBA form however it just keeps writing over the top row and does not edit the specific rows data. I am trying to get it to edit the data that is showing and not overwrite the top lines data.  any help is appreciated.    The code I am using is:

```
Private Sub cmdupdate_Click()

 Dim rowselect As Single
 rowselect = rowselect + 2
 Rows(rowselect).Select

 Cells(rowselect, 1) = Me.txtname.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.txtposition.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.txtassigned.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 4) = Me.cmbsection.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 5) = Me.txtdate.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 7) = Me.txtjoint.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 8) = Me.txtDAS.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 9) = Me.txtDEROS.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 10) = Me.txtDOR.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 11) = Me.txtTAFMSD.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 12) = Me.txtDOS.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 13) = Me.txtPAC.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 14) = Me.ComboTSC.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 15) = Me.txtTSC.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 16) = Me.txtAEF.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 17) = Me.txtPCC.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 18) = Me.txtcourses.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 19) = Me.txtseven.Value
 Cells(rowselect, 20) = Me.txtcle.Value

 End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your top row? Where is the specific row you want to edit? Please show by image..

Comment: There is no increment to the rowselect variable. hence, it will overwrite on row 2 if you are running the same code again

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to add the photo.  I want to be able to edit all the rows, but individually.  I have a next and previous button that will bring up specific rows in the form but the edit button using the above code will always overwrite the 2nd row instead of overwriting the data that is pulled up in the form.

Comment: Naresh thank you for the information.  How will I fix that and add the variable code.  Would it be rows(rowselect).select.variable?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. It seems you want to update new row in excel file with text in a userform when you click a command button on the userform ?

Comment: I want to update an existing rows data from the user form.

Comment: any thoughts on what I can do now?

Answer (score 0):

replace following part for rowselect..

```
Dim rowselect As Integer
If Range("A:A").Find(Me.txtname.Value) Is Nothing Then
    Msg = "The Text Name could not be found in Column A" & _
    vbLf & "Do you want to create a new record?"    ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1 ' Define buttons.
    Title = "CAUTION"   ' Define title.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, "CAUTION")  '(Msg, Style, Title)
    If Response = vbYes Then
    rowselect = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'This will give you number of the first blank row below you table in Column A 
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
Else
rowselect = Range("A:A").Find(Me.txtname.Value).Row
End If

' and then all the following shall work correctly each time you cilck the button .. if the form has all those fields
Cells(rowselect, 1) = Me.txtname.Value
Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.txtposition.Value
Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.txtassigned.Value ' and so on
```

Comment: Thank you but now it just adds the data to the bottom row versus updating the row the data is on already.  Thank you for the assistance but do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: If you want to update existing record.. then you will have to link the row number with the unique id of the record and lookup for that row and select while updating

Comment: what is unique id of the record.. is it  txtname?.... Assuming it is txtname i am changing the answer

Comment: Thank you for the help I am feeling a little better about all the code.  Although I was wanting it to edit the data in the specific row with the existing, not add a row to the bottom.  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want only to update the record without adding a new one, the code will still work.. You have to define unique ID for the record and find the range.row to update

Comment: Answer edited to give you a message box option to create a new record