# How to insert data from userform to a specific row with a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a userform that can find the "Sales" value in column E and then input the remaining data to the same row.

```
Set APAC = Sheet2
APAC.Activate
Range("E18:E1888").Select
For Each D In Selection
    If D.Value = "TWO.Sales.Value" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next D


Rows(D.Row).Select

    D.Offset(0, 2).Value = TWO.RSA.Value
    D.Offset(0, 3).Value = TWO.Part.Value
    D.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWO.Part.Value, Worksheets("DataEntry").Range("T2:U70").Value, 2, False)
    D.Offset(0, 5).Value = TWO.Program.Value
    D.Offset(0, 6).Value = TWO.QTY.Value
    Sheet2.Activate
```

This is my code but

> run time error '91'

occurs.

Comment: Wecome to SO...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60650179/9808063

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: What if you have same sales Value for two records?

Comment: I am having error on the "Rows(D.Row).select" line

Comment: First, declare all your variables. Add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module. You will find that `TWO.RSA` is an object that hasn't been declared. Then don't *Select* or *Activate* anything. `For Each D in Sheet2.Range("E18:E1888")` will have the exact same result as what your 3 lines of code generate - minus the clutter.

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comment.. Here is a very similar question ...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60650179/9808063 ... You dont have to loop through to find sales value .. Also is D range or just a variant?

Answer (score 1):

> I am having error on the "Rows(D.Row).select" line – Jacob 2 mins ago

That means `"TWO.Sales.Value"` was not found in `Range("E18:E1888")` and hence `D` was nothing. You need to check if the value was found. Also I have a feeling that you wanted `If D.Value = TWO.Sales.Value Then` instead of `If D.Value = "TWO.Sales.Value" Then`

Also there is no need to `Select/Activate`. You can directly work with the objects. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Whenever you are working with `VLookup`, it is better to handle the error that may pop up when a match is not found. There are various ways to do it. I have shown one way in the code below.

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim APAC As Worksheet
    Dim curRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim Ret

    Set APAC = Sheet2

    With APAC
        For Each aCell In .Range("E18:E1888")
            If aCell.Value = TWO.Sales.Value Then
                curRow = aCell.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next aCell

        If curRow = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        Else
            .Range("G" & curRow).Value = TWO.RSA.Value
            .Range("H" & curRow).Value = TWO.Part.Value

            On Error Resume Next
            Ret = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TWO.Part.Value, _
                  Worksheets("DataEntry").Range("T2:U70").Value, 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Ret <> "" Then .Range("I" & curRow).Value = Ret

            .Range("J" & curRow).Value = TWO.Program.Value
            .Range("K" & curRow).Value = TWO.QTY.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: If the range `.Range("E18:E1888")` is dynamic then you may want to find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) and then use the range as `.Range("E18:E" & LastRow)`

Comment: you also can replace the first loop to look for sales value with Range.Find

Comment: Yup one can as shown [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: @SiddharthRout i tried your code but they it is saying that they can't find TWO.Sales.Value in the range E18:E1888 even though it is there.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help. I use the Range.find function in the end as i find it easier.

Comment: @Jacob: Probabaly that is because there is some space or it is case sensitive. Try by replacing `If aCell.Value = TWO.Sales.Value Then` with `If Upper(Trim(aCell.Value)) = Upper(Trim(TWO.Sales.Value)) Then`. Yes using `.Find` in a better way though. Anyways, did the rest of the code help?